# My additional accounts are gone

Tags: accounts

Now my metamask crashed and I had to reinstall.
Only my original account is showing, not the additional 9 account which were created on the original account.
Is there any way to link these other accounts again (i have the adresses).

Please make my day!

Sven

Answer (score 1):

If they were addresses made from the same mnemonic, then pressing "Create account" multiple times will add the same accounts in the same order that you originally created them

Answer (score 0):

yes, but it's a manual process to add each one with the private key i.e they're not remembered

click on the account icon, then Import Account

good luck. I hope you have the keys

[image: 0x4686F132f1E6B1547bcE8516D1931C595ed30E45]